# Is there a closed form of $\int\frac{x\ln x}{\arctan x}dx$?

Tags: integration, closed-form-expressions

Consider the integral$$\int\dfrac{x\ln x}{\arctan x}dx\label1\tag1$$While I have made some progress on computing the antiderivative, I would like to know whether or not there is a closed form of it.

---

This is the progress I have made so far:$$I=\int\dfrac{x\ln x}{\arctan x}\\\overset{x=\tan u,\,dx=\sec^2(x)}=\int\dfrac{\tan(u)\ln(\tan u)\sec^2(u)}udu\\\overset{\frac d{dx}\sec^2(x)=2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}=\dfrac12\int\left(\dfrac d{du}\sec^2(u)\right)\dfrac{\ln(\tan u)}udu$$I then used the integration by parts formula$$\int u(x)v'(x)dx=u(x)v(x)-\int u'(x)v(x)dx$$with $u(x)=\frac{\ln(\tan x)}x$ and $v(x)=\sec^2(x)$. Now, the integral is equal to$$\dfrac12\sec^2(u)\ln(\tan u)-\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\csc(u)\sec^3(u)}u-\dfrac{\sec^2(u)\ln(\tan u)}{u^2}du$$which since I have a $\sec^2(u)\ln(\tan u)$ outside of an integral, I can substitute $\arctan(x)=u$ into that to get$$\dfrac12\sec^2(\arctan x)\ln(x)-\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\csc(u)\sec^3(u)}u-\dfrac{\sec^2(u)\ln(\tan u)}{u^2}du$$however this is all of the progress that I have been able to make so far, so my question is

> Is there a closed form of $\eqref1$, or have I made as much progress on this integral as is possible?

Comment: Even Rubi cannot give the antiderivative ...

Comment: Have you tried the Risch algorithm?

Comment: @RyanBudney Sorry about not responding. No, I'm not familiar enough with the Risch algorithm to try to implement it, sorry.